# Bivariate infinite series: explicit sum?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, multivariable-calculus

Let $S_n(x,y)=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac{x^k}{k!}y^{n-k}$, and consider the series $S(x,y)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty S_n(x,y)$, where $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$.  My question is: does this series have an explicit sum (i.e. closed-form expression)?

The main reason why such a sum may exist is that if the binomial coefficient $\binom{n}{k}$ were set equal to unity in $S_n$, then the series becomes $S(x,y)=\frac{\exp x}{1-y}$ by the Cauchy product.  It is possible that we have a "simple" modification of this function that produces the binomial coefficients in $S_n$.  This seems plausible, since it can be shown that $S$ is absolutely convergent for all $x$ and for $y\in(-1,1)$, which mimics the properties of $\frac{\exp x}{1-y}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have $$S_{n}\left(x,y\right)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\dbinom{n}{k}\frac{x^{k}}{k!}y^{n-k}=y^{n}L_{n}\left(-\frac{x}{y}\right)
 $$ where $L_{n}\left(x\right)
 $ is the [Laguerre polinomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laguerre_polynomials#Recursive_definition.2C_closed_form.2C_and_generating_function). If we put $u=-x/y
 $ we have, by their [generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laguerre_polynomials#Recursive_definition.2C_closed_form.2C_and_generating_function), $$\sum_{n\geq0}S_{n}\left(x,y\right)=\sum_{n\geq0}y^{n}L_{n}\left(u\right)=\frac{1}{1-y}e^{-yu/\left(1-y\right)}=\frac{1}{1-y}e^{x/\left(1-y\right)}
 $$ obviously, where it makes sense.

Comment: Fantastic.  Thank you, sir.